# Cannot print pdf pages with images

Tags: 12.04, printing, pdf

When I try to print a PDF file that contains images, the printing stops just before the first page that contains an image. If the first page contains an image, only a single blank page is printed.

I saw that there is [an old bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/836278), relating to Ubuntu 11.04.

However, I have 12.04, and I updated cups-pdf, and I still get this error.

Comment: Can you plz check whether `cups-pdf` on your system is >= 2.5.1-6? Also, have you upgraded your system from < 12.04, or installed 12.04 from scratch?

Comment: Do you experience the problem when trying to print a pdf file out on paper? Or are you trying to "print to pdf" (print-to-file)? Or both?

Comment: apt-get tells me that "cups-pdf is already the newest version." How can I check what version it is? I work on a fresh 12.04 install. I experience the problem only when trying to print a pdf on paper.

Comment: hmm, I'd use **synaptic** to check the version. If it's a clean install, I'm not sure if purging will help -- but neither should it harm.

Comment: Or, type `apt-cache policy cups-pdf` in a terminal and hit `enter`. I see "cups-pdf: // Installed: (none) // Candidate: 2.6.1-7 // Version table: // 2.6.1-7 0 // 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe i386 Packages".

Comment: I see:
  Installed: 2.6.1-6
  Candidate: 2.6.1-6

Comment: I had suffered this problem for long. It may be related to imagemagick. Please check if you are running imagemagick or graphicsmagick*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround that worked for me

I installed first (I did not had it installed):

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

Then I printed the PDF from Evince using the new PDF printer that is added by cups-pdf first. The output goes to ~/PDF (can be configured in `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`).

Then I opened the pdf file generated by cups-pdf printer to Evince and printed it again to my real printer.

It worked.

Comment: I printed from Evince but, the output file (which I indeed found in ~/PDF) did not contain the pages with the images...

Comment: But, the idea of printing to PDF is useful in itself - it allows to check the problem without wasting paper.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to

- ***purge*** `cups-pdf` (in **synaptic**, "mark for **complete** removal");
- then **re-install** `cups-pdf`.

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue that print a blank PDF file. Purge then re- install fixed my problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge cups-pdf
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Comment: Didn't work for me...